# Take date input from user and save it as date in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java.util.date

I'm trying to take input from user in `(dd/mm/yy)` format, save it in same format and pass it with getter, setter to another class. I have tried this way:

This is what I have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
    Guest gstObject = new Guest();
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter check-in date (dd/mm/yy):");
        String cindate = input.next();
        Date date1 = myFormat.parse(cindate);
        gstObject.setIndate(date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this code I'm getting an exception when I give input in (27012017 or 27 01 2017):

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "27"
  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
  at edu.lfa.GuestArrayList.main(GuestArrayList.java:49)
```

Please point out what mistake I have made.

Comment: Use `input.nextLine()` instead of `input.next()`. Also, you're prompting the user for a different format than your `SimpleDateFormat` actually accepts, so watch out for that.

Comment: So if you want them to enter `dd/mm/yy`, why did you write `myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");`?

Comment: try entering "27 01 2017" because you date format is "dd MM yyyy" or change the format to "dd/MM/yyyy".

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) javadoc for `next()`, this is what it says:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

Default delimiter is space and hence, it only reads `27`. You need to read the whole line by using `nextLine()`. Following should work:

```
System.out.println("Enter check-in date (dd/mm/yy):");
String cindate = input.nextLine();
if(null != cindate && cindate.trim().length() > 0){
    Date date1 = myFormat.parse(cindate);
}
```

**Update** To check for `null` or empty string, you need to wrap the parsing code inside `if` condition.

Comment: Metha I changed `String cindate = input.next();` to `String cindate = input.nextLine();`  Now i'm getting error without entering date. Error is 

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
 at edu.lfa.GuestArrayList.main(GuestArrayList.java:49)`

Comment: I have updated my answer to include null and empty string check. Basically, you can skip the parsing if the input is null or just space and show error message.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers addressed how to use `Scanner` correctly. I'll address some other issues.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid the `java.util.Date` class like the Plague.

Also, you are inappropriately trying to represent a date-only value with a date+time class.

Instead, use `java.time.LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To parse the user's input, specify a formatting pattern to match *exactly* the expected input from your user.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.parse( "dd/mm/uuuu" );
```

Parse user input.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

On your business class `Guest`, make the member variable of type `LocalDate`.

To persist the `LocalDate`, you can serialize to text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Simply call `toString`.

```
String output = guest.getLocalDate().toString();
```

> 2017-01-23

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).