# Two steps running at once in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java.util.date

I have the following code to take the input from the user under case 1 of switch statement:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
  Guest gstObject = new Guest();

  System.out.println("Enter reservation ID:");
  gstObject.setId(input.nextInt());

  System.out.println("Enter first name:");
  gstObject.setfName(input.next());

  System.out.println("Enter last name:");
  gstObject.setfName(input.next());               


  System.out.println("Enter check-in date (dd/mm/yy):");
  String cindate = input.nextLine();
  if(null != cindate && cindate.trim().length() > 0){
     Date date1 = myFormat.parse(cindate);
  } 

  System.out.println("Enter check-out date (dd/mm/yy):");
  String outdate = input.nextLine();  
  if(null != outdate && outdate.trim().length() > 0){
     Date date2 = myFormat.parse(outdate);
  }
}
```

[image]
The code takes input one by one simultaneously upto `Enter last name:` but runs last two `check-in date` and `check-out date` step at once and doesn't ask for input of the `check-in date`.

I tried by switching places of these input. I also ignores to take input that is on the top and takes input that is at the bottom. Also tried by placing `check-in date` and `check-out date` at the very top turnwise. They ignore to take inputs and jumps directly to `Enter reservation ID`.

How can i solve this matter ?

Comment: you already asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881501/take-date-input-from-user-and-save-it-as-date-in-java so please continue with one question you can make comment and you can edit your post

Comment: Couldn't find solution. I also added `scan.nextLine();` in place of `input.nextLine(); `  as suggested in the above mentioned (duplicate) but it gives me warning cannot find symbol `scan` and to create scan class.

Comment: scan is the same with your input thats all

Comment: can you elaborate it with example please. like `scan.nextLine();`  ?

Comment: return to your first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881501/take-date-input-from-user-and-save-it-as-date-in-java so we can help you this question is already closed

Comment: did you tried my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41881678/5558072